# How to get the image in summernote bootstrap using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I am using a summernote in bootstrap as my editor. It looks good and I'm fond using it. I can get the texts inserted by the user, however, the problem is that when the user inserted an image, the src of image returns to a binary text. I dont want to save this whole text of the src into the database, instead, I want the image to be saved directly to my disk drive and copy the image name and save it into the database.

Does anybody know this?

Comment: its by default converted to Base64. you can add the API to upload image by jQuery, check the Issues on uts github

Comment: Got this on official page 
[onImageUpload](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html#callbacks-onImageUpload)